# Ajax jQuery.when() with each() cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a dynamic number of elements with data-url attribute that contains URL for ajax call which return its HTML content.

```
<div class="element" data-url="data1.php"></div>
<div class="element" data-url="data2.php"></div>
<div class="element" data-url="data3.php"></div>
...
```

I need to load their content via AJAX and after it's all done do something with it.

I don't think I can use .ajaxStop() because after these calls there are more different ajax calls and I can't wait until they are all finished.

So I tried to use jQuery.when() with .each() cycle to go through all the elements and load their content, but .done() function fires before all the ajax calls in the cycle are finished.

```
$.when(
    $('.element').each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $.get($(el).data('url'), function(data) {
            $(el).html(data);
        });
    })
).done(function() {
    // do something after all calls are finished
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your logic is that `each()` returns a jQuery object. As this isn't a promise `$.when()` resolves immediately and `done()` is called before all/any of your `$.get` requests have completed.

To fix this create an array of promises from the `$.get()` calls and apply these to `$.when()`. Try this:

```js
var promises = $('.element').map(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  return $.get($el.data('url'), function(data) {
    $el.html(data);
  });
}).get()

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
  // do something after all calls are finished
});
```

Also note that while this will work, potentially flooding your server with requests in a loop is not a scalable solution. A better pattern would be to aggregate all the `data-url` attributes from the `.element` elements in to a single request and then update the DOM manually after this request completes.